# Calling parent function after setInterval timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

In my react app I am using a timer component. I want this component to run in the background and call a parent function after a certain time. The code is giving error. My code is

parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Timer from './timer';


class Parent extends Component {

    finish(){
        console.log('fininsh')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Timer data={this.finish.bind(this)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

timer component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            fin: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({fin: true})
        }, 10000);
    }

    childfinish = () => {
        this.props.data.finish
    }


    render() {

        const {fin} = this.state;

        if(fin){
            return(
            <div>
                {this.childfinish};
            </div>
            )
        } else {
        return (
              <div>
                  <h1>Counting...</h1>
              </div>
         )
        }
    }
}

export default Timer;
```

the error is

Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Timer from './timer';


class Parent extends Component {

    finish(){
        console.log('fininsh')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Timer data={{callfinish : this.finish.bind(this)}} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

Child Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            fin: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({fin: true})
        }, 10000);
    } 

    childfinish = () => {
        clearInterval(this.myInterval);
        this.props.data.callfinish();
    }


    render() {

        const {fin} = this.state;

        if(fin){
            this.childfinish();
            return (
                <div></div>
            )
        } else {
        return (
              <div>
                  <h1>Counting...</h1>
              </div>
         )
        }
    }
}

export default Timer;
```

The parent function will run after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`data` prop does not contain function `finish()`.

Remove `{this.childfinish}` from `render()` and

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
   this.setState({fin: true})
   this.props.data(); 
   }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: 'Functions are not valid as a React child' error coming after the change